# CommunicationState listener?

Tags: c#, wcf, events

Does anyone know of a way to create a listener for a proxy so that when the CommunicationState has changed I can invoke an action or a method?

An example, I want to update my WCF service for a code change. Since the application is in its early development code changes are very frequent. However, instead of annoying my employees with an email tell them that hey they need to restart their application. I would rather avoid them having to restart the app and having to send them an email. I would rather write a listener that looks at the communication state of a service and if it has changed to a faulted stated then attempt to reconnect.

**Edit**

Maybe some more context here.

```
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);
Subscriber = new SubscriptionService.MySubscriptionServiceClient(context);
Subscriber.Subscribe("");
```

So basically I want to know when the subscription service has stopped so that I can attempt to reconnect every 60 seconds or so. I tried looking for an event in the Subscriber service but I didn't see anything. Would I need to implement something on the service end?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# WCF" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Ok...is there any particular reason why? It would be nice if you specified instead of just making a statement.

Comment: Because "that's what the tags are for".

Comment: Also, see [When should we remove pseudo-tags from a title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61055/when-should-we-remove-pseudo-tags-from-a-title).

Comment: `IClientChannel` has some [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.iclientchannel_events.aspx) that you might find useful. Especially `Faulted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Faulted event available on the `InnerChannel` property of your generated client class. The `State` property of the client class is just a wrapper for `InnerChannel.State`, so this should work as you desire.

(For reference, you can also use the similarly named event on `ChannelFactory<TChannel>` if you are creating communication channels in code rather than using generated proxies.)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to successfully latch on to the Faulted event and re-subscribe the clients to the service. This works flawlessly!